# Solspace Freeform: loop over all form errors

Tags: templating, form, plugin-freeform

I can only find the following method in the documentation (https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/docs/form/#templates)

```
form.hasErrors
```

Is there an array available with all the error messages combined? I'm looking for a way to iterate over all form errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently isn't a way to get all errors directly from the form, but you could do it this way for now:

```
{% for row in form %}
    {% for field in row %}
        {% for error in field.getErrors %}
            {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ok too bad it isn't stored globally for the form, but this'll work for now :)